# Percentage for event to happen PHP

Tags: php

My question is: if I have 2 variables, for example `a=70 b=30` 70 and 30 mean percentages for event to happen, how can make php script to simulate this chanсes of dropping variable 'a' or 'b'.

Example:

```
a=70
b=30
```

So if i start the php script i have 70% chance to see 'a' and 30% to see 'b'.
Sorry for bad description of my question, I haven't done this before.

Comment: Do you want to change the wording from calculate to something like *simulate* ?  That would seem to match the answer attempts you are getting.

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward since the input for your program is exactly the same as the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, for natural numbers a>0 and b>0

```
if(mt_rand(1,$a+$b)>$a){
    echo 'b';
} else {
    echo 'a';
}
```

Comment: The idea is that you sum up the possibilities: 70 cases should be A, and 30 B. (This is what the percentage means). The you assign the numbers 1 through (A+B) to those cases, and ask mt_rand (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) to generate a random number between those bounds (inclusively); and it will pick any one of them with equal probability.

Comment: Seems like it works. Thanks i will test it.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(mt_rand(0, 100) > 70){
    echo 'b';
}else{
    echo 'a';
}
```

Of course you can say this isn't "true random". But I'm not sure that you'll be bothered about that.

Comment: According to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php both bounds are inclusive, so this is bugous.